# Synonym suggestion: [plant(s)] and [botany]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

Inline with the insect(s)->entomology synonym, why not a plant(s)->botany synonym?

Comment: @kmm thanks for suggesting the tag, but it looks like you suggested [botany]->[plant]. Shouldn't it be [plant]->[botany] ?

Comment: Been thinking the same thing so good suggestion.

Comment: FWIW I've gone ahead and voted down [botany]->[plant]; once someone else votes it down I'll go ahead and suggest [plant]->[botany] now that my rep is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to bother with suggesting synonyms that way, the requirements are so high that it is almost impossible to have a community-created tag synonym on a beta site.

I've created the synonym now and merged the tags.